# How would formula change in Base 6?

Tags: number-systems

How would the following formulars change if we use a base 6 arabic number system?

- quadratic formula (=midnight formula)
- Einsteins e=mc^2
- pi
- circle A=pi*r^2

It would be counted like this: `0 1 2 3 4 5 10 11 12 13 14 15 20 21 22 23 24 25 30 31 32 33 34 35 40 41 42 43 44 45 50 51 52 53 54 55 100 101....`

Comment: First of all, $\pi$ is not a formula, it is a number. Secondly, formulas in general are independent of the chosen base, as long as you do the operations correctly.

Comment: "pi" is not a formula. The other ones wouldn't change in any way.

Comment: The numbers $5$ $15$ $25$ $35$ $45$ and $55$ do not belong in your list.

Comment: Numbers are numbers. They don't change just because you choose to write them using a different base.

Comment: Perhaps that you might want to know that, in base $5$, $\pi=3,03232214\ldots$

Comment: Note that the system using the numerals $0$ through $5$ is base _six_ (just like the system using the numerals $0$ through $9$ is base ten, not base nine)

Answer (score 3):

The *representation* of $\pi$ will change, but the *value* of $\pi$ will not change.

None of the formulae change.

Answer (score 1):

Formulas are independent from the base you use.

Every number will be converted correctly and properly, and thence you would keep using the same "old" formulas as always. What will change will be the involved numbers, **not** the formulas.

Comment: Numerals **not** numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: They wouldn't change at all.